# Scraping href with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the CO2 per resource trend table data from this url: pcaiso.com/todaysoutlook/pages/emissions.html

The href attribute of the contains the dataset for the chart (as a very long string) I was attempting to return this attribute, but my code is returning a zero set for the following request, no matter how hard I try and google other suggestions.

```
url = 'http://www.caiso.com/todaysoutlook/pages/emissions.html'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
html = soup.find("a", {"class": "dropdown-item"})
print(html)
```

Any thoughts are appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you really are asking about is why the element does not have an `href` attribute when you inspect it in your code.  The reason is, when you request the HTML page from the server it actually returns a static page without any chart data.  When you view this page in a web browser, it runs some JavaScript code that queries the backend and populates the chart data dynamically. So you'll need to modify your approach to get that data.

One option is to manually inspect the page in your browser, reverse-engineer how it fetches the data, and do the same thing in your code. Most web browser have built-in developer tools that can help with this.

Another option is to use a browser automation tool like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) to load the page in a web browser environment and scrape the data from there. This is less efficient, but might be easier for someone inexperienced in web programming because you can treat the JavaScript functionality as a "black box" and interact with the page more like how a real user would.

Comment: I can also reproduce your result, but the text string I'm trying to pull here is actually the href attribute.  It's too long to copy and paste but I'll put the first few characters: "data:text/csv;charset=utf8,%2004%2F13%2F2021%2C00%3A00%". This string contains the data from the chart, text separated by "%2". Basically, I just want the content of the graph though, and my strategy was just going to be to text parse this string. Other suggestions for getting the data a different way is also welcome! Thank you

Comment: @Sophie I see, when you wrote "my code is returning a zero set for the following request" what you actually meant was "when I request the page in my code, the element doesn't have an href attribute". I'll update my answer to explain why.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.